# Why $\prod_{n\in \mathbb N}\left([-2^{-n},2^{-n}]\cap\mathbb Q\right)\subset l_2$ is countable and dense in $l_2$?

Tags: general-topology

Why $$\prod_{n\in \mathbb N}\left([-2^{-n},2^{-n}]\cap\mathbb Q\right)\subset l_2$$ is countable and dense in $l_2$? Please explain.

**My attempt**

I just try to relate with $\mathbb Q ^\mathbb N$. But  i could not get the map. Help me.

Comment: What is the definition of $l_2$?

Comment: It's neither countable nor dense. It spans a dense subspace, but is not dense itself. Since $[-2^{-n},2^{-n}]\cap\mathbb{Q}$ is equipotent to $\mathbb{Q}$, the cardinality of the product is $\aleph_0^{\aleph_0} = 2^{\aleph_0}$.